# how can declare variable of <div>

Tags: asp.net

how can declare a variable of type `<div>` in asp.net

```
<div id="b" runat="server"/>
```

Code

```
 get(b);

private void Get(<div> d)
{
  d.Visible=false;

}
```

i can do this work?How can...

Comment: For what it's worth, the `<asp:Panel>` also renders as a `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to declare a div on the server side.

```
var div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

The answer is still the same, use an HtmlGenericControl.

```
private void Get(HtmlGenericControl d)
{
   d.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within ASP.NET itself, you can just use a `<DIV>` no problem. IF you want to access it from the code behind, you can use line like any other contrl

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">
...
</div>
```

If you're trying to generate one in your code behind, you can use the HtmlGenericControl.

Answer (score -2):

used System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

Get(b)

private void Get(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl d)
{
  d.Visiable=false;

}